# How to get current logged in user with open id connect identity jwt bearer net core

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

Hello I am trying to get current user but nothing seems to work every resource I find brings null.
this is the code in my startup

```
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();



            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
    IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
    options =>
    {
        var onTokenValidated = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            await onTokenValidated(context);

        };
    });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
                o.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
       o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
```

Comment: Please add more descriptions and pinpoint the question.

Comment: Also, add info about how you have set up the IdentityServer